# i need to create a smooth alpha transition in webgl

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, render

Need to create a smooth alpha transition from three color vertices without, breaking. what am i doing wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lm208gjq/

```js
var vertexShaderText = 
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'attribute vec2 vertPosition;',
'attribute vec4 vertColor;',
'varying vec4 fragColor;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'  fragColor = vertColor;',
'  gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition, 0.0, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragmentShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'varying vec4 fragColor;',
'void main()',
'{',
'  gl_FragColor = fragColor;',
'}'
].join('\n');

var InitDemo = function () {
 console.log('This is working');

 var canvas = document.getElementById('opengl_output');
 var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

 if (!gl) {
  console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
  gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
 }

 if (!gl) {
  alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
 }

 gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 //
 // Create shaders
 // 
 var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
 var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

 gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
 gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);

 gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
  return;
 }

 gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
  return;
 }

 var program = gl.createProgram();
 gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
 gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
 gl.linkProgram(program);
 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  return;
 }
 gl.validateProgram(program);
 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR validating program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  return;
 }

 //
 // Create buffer
 //
 var triangleVertices = 
 [ // X, Y,       R, G, B, A
  0.0, 0.5,    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0001,
  0.5, -0.5,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
 ];

 var triangleVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferObject);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 var positionAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertPosition');
 var colorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertColor');
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  positionAttribLocation, // Attribute location
  2, // Number of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
  gl.FALSE,
  6 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // Size of an individual vertex
  0 // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
 );
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  colorAttribLocation, // Attribute location
  4, // Number of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
  gl.FALSE,
  6 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // Size of an individual vertex
  2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
 );
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ZERO);

 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);

 //
 // Main render loop
 //
 gl.useProgram(program);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
};

InitDemo();
```

```html
<canvas id="opengl_output" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Why is this code producing another triangle?

Im new to this webgl programming, it could be something simple iv'e tried to change the attribute buffer with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default alpha compositing is [premultiplied alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description).

Either you've to disable `premultipliedAlpha`,

```js
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', { premultipliedAlpha: false });
```

**Or** you've to multiply the RGB color channels by the ALPHA channel in the fragment shader:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor.rgb * fragColor.a, fragColor.a);
```

See [WebGLFundamentals - WebGL and Alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html)

```js
var vertexShaderText = 
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'attribute vec2 vertPosition;',
'attribute vec4 vertColor;',
'varying vec4 fragColor;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'  fragColor = vertColor;',
'  gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition, 0.0, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragmentShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'varying vec4 fragColor;',
'void main()',
'{',
'  gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor.rgb * fragColor.a, fragColor.a);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var InitDemo = function () {
 console.log('This is working');

 var canvas = document.getElementById('opengl_output');
 var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl' /*, { premultipliedAlpha: false }*/);

 if (!gl) {
  console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
  gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl' /*, { premultipliedAlpha: false }*/);
 }

 if (!gl) {
  alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
 }

 gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 //
 // Create shaders
 // 
 var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
 var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

 gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
 gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);

 gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
  return;
 }

 gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
  return;
 }

 var program = gl.createProgram();
 gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
 gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
 gl.linkProgram(program);
 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  return;
 }
 gl.validateProgram(program);
 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR validating program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  return;
 }

 //
 // Create buffer
 //
 var triangleVertices = 
 [ // X, Y,       R, G, B, A
  0.0, 0.5,    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0001,
  0.5, -0.5,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
 ];

 var triangleVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexBufferObject);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 var positionAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertPosition');
 var colorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertColor');
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  positionAttribLocation, // Attribute location
  2, // Number of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
  gl.FALSE,
  6 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // Size of an individual vertex
  0 // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
 );
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  colorAttribLocation, // Attribute location
  4, // Number of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, // Type of elements
  gl.FALSE,
  6 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // Size of an individual vertex
  2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT // Offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
 );
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ZERO);

 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);

 //
 // Main render loop
 //
 gl.useProgram(program);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
};

InitDemo();
```

```html
<canvas id="opengl_output" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```